# ImportError: No module named pandas On Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, windows-10, importerror

I have recently installed python3.6 to learn about. I installed pandas using pip.
It has installed successfully.

When I write a simple program to check using python IDLE and run the program I get the error:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

I check for PATH library on windows and it has an entry for Site-library location where pandas is installed.

How do I overcome this problem? I checked for all the tips available from different questions, but not progressing :(

Thanks for any help to get the environment in right shape.

Comment: Spelling, formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you should just try:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had to uninstall few packages & reinstall. It started working.